# How to implement uint8 3d array Matlab with 2 cubes?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I must generate 3D array that simulates DICOM. Array is `uint8` format, where value of the array determine the pixel brightness. There should be two cubes in the 3D `uint8` array.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to implament a uint8 3D array with 2 cubes inside?

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize it with zeros of the correct size and then assign two chunks at a time.

```
A = zeros(100, 100, 40, 'uint8');

% Create one cube of 1's
A(5:45, 5:45, 3:17) = 1;

% Create the second cube of 1's
A(55:95, 55:95, 23:37) = 1;
```

Comment: @Szymon Be sure to see the update which makes sure that it's `uint8`. Thanks @beaker